# Use a variable name in an erb include call

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm using Sinatra and I'd like to include another erb file in one of my views but using a variable for the file name.

I was thinking something like this may work but I get an error saying no such file could be found.

```
<%= erb :'layout/nav/#{device_type}' %>
```

Currently I'm using the below switch statement to achieve the desired results but the above would be cleaner and less code.

```
<% case device_type
   when 'mobile'%>
    <%= erb :'layout/nav/mobile' %>
    <% when 'tablet' %>
    <%= erb :'layout/nav/tablet' %>
    <% else %>
    <%= erb :'layout/nav/desktop' %>
    <% end  %>
```

Thanks

Giles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that could work, you just need to use double quotes to interpolate strings.

Try

```
<%= erb :"layout/nav/#{device_type}" %>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @jmromer! I hate it when little gotchas like that trip you up ha, one to remember!